# Getting peergoneevent exception

Tags: tomcat7, tomcat8, weblogic12c, oracle-agile-plm

I have a web application deployed on tomcat whick interacts with Agile PLM on weblogic server.

**Issue:**

I have to test the connection at regular intervals so when i test the connections they are successful but when i restart the Agile Plm on weblogic and test the connection i get following exception.

```
<Mar 6, 2018 10:14:34 AM PST> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000429> <Muxer received error: weblogic/rjvm/PeerGoneEvent
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/rjvm/PeerGoneEvent.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/rjvm/PeerGoneEvent
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.peerGone(RJVMImpl.java:1605)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.peerGone(RJVMImpl.java:1577)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.gotExceptionReceiving(RJVMImpl.java:1210)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.gotExceptionReceiving(ConnectionManager.java:1173)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.gotExceptionReceiving(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:583)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.hasException(MuxableSocketT3.java:592)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverExceptionAndCleanup(SocketMuxer.java:846)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.deliverHasException(SocketMuxer.java:780)
        at weblogic.socket.JavaSocketMuxer.processSockets(JavaSocketMuxer.java:409)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteRequestAdapter.execute(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:21)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```

Any suggestions why this is happening

```
params.put(AgileSessionFactory.URL, attrMap.get("url"));
        params.put(AgileSessionFactory.USERNAME, attrMap.get("uname"));
        params.put(AgileSessionFactory.PASSWORD, attrMap.get("password"));
        session = AgileSessionFactory.createSessionEx(params);
```

Comment: we have the same problem. Did you find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Ben sorry for delayed response. no i still have not found solution for that...please let me know if you find solution for this. We can avoid this issue if we restart tomcat after restarting Agile.

Comment: yes that's the same way as we workaround. But that means manually work which is not always immediately possible. If I find a solution I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank You...will do the same

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of possible scenarios that could be causing this:

Have you installed this web application on the File Manager tomcat? If so, the error is an indication that existing agile classes in the FileManager tomcat's classpath is preventing required classes from download. Try moving the application to a separate tomcat.

Are you closing the session after your check and re-establishing the session each time?< If not, please try doing that.

May be the check is running before the managed nodes are up and only the admin node is up and running. Please verify that the managed nodes are up too.

Comment: Thank You for the response. My web-app is deployed on custom tomcat, not on file manager tomcat.I am closing the session every time the connection test is performed. I have no idea on how to manage the nodes. i have to do some research on how to manage the nodes. Thank you for pointing me in the direction. Thanks.